# JQuery - .keyup() with if statement (2 digit numbers)

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, logic, onkeyup

if I type 3 on the `<input id="test">`, the result is `true`.
but if I type 12 on the `<input id="test">`, then the result is `false` supposed (true) because 12 greater than 3.

I have code like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  var minim = $('#minimal').val();
  $('#test').keyup(function() {
    if ($(this).val() > minim) {
      console.log('true');
    }
    else {
      console.log('false');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<Input id="test" type="number" />
<Input id="minimal" type="number" value="2" />
```

Please help me :(

Comment: What you actually want to achieve in this code. Explain your question in detail

Comment: You are comparing strings, you need to convert the values to numbers

Answer (score 1):

val() - return string

try

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var minim = parseInt($('#minimal').val());
  $('#test').keyup(function() {
    if (parseInt($(this).val()) > minim) {
      console.log('true');
    }
    else {
      console.log('false');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: You should *always* include a radix when using [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

Comment: I just wanted to convey the essence :)